# Compartir varibles en bloques de flask

Tags: python, flask

Estoy usando Flask con python (soy nuevo con Flask, asi que me disculpo si es muy basico). Lo que quiero es compartir una variable en bloques. Ejemplo rapido, la variable "Hola", quiero pasarla de index() a generate(). Pense que "Global" lo resolvia, pero, me lanza un error cuando la llamo desde generate.

**Nota: recuerden que es un ejemplo, lo que busco es usar una variable de un bloque en otro (lo digo porque en ese ejemplo no cuesta nada escribir "Hola", en mi codigo original no puedo hacerlo).**

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
   global hola
   hola = "Hola"
   return render_template("index.html", saludo_para_index = hola)

def generate():
    print(hola)

@app.route("/registro")
   return "Pagina de ejemplo"
```

Comment: si en principios llamas a la funcion `generate()` te dara error, trata de declara la variable antes que todo

Comment: Solo necesito pasar los datos que tiene index() a generate(), sin llamar a la funcion.

Comment: La función se ejecuta al momento de ser llamada , por más que declares la variable a fuera, nunca aparecerá tu `print()` por qué este wsta dentro de la función `generate`